# last array values being repeated for all the previous arrays: Python

Tags: python, arrays, random, initialization

I am trying to generate three different arrays of vx[], vy[] and vz[] for 2 atoms (natoms). I am able to print these different values when I initialize the arrays just after the initialization. However, when I try to print the values later it give the same array, ie. vz[] for all the arrays vx[], vy[] and vz[]. Am I missing something? I tried using different loops, but still cannot get it. I also tried copying the arrays in new arrays, as velx (=vx), vely and velz but its of no use. Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong?

```
    for i in xrange(0,natoms,1):
            x = random.random()
            vx[i]=4.0*math.sqrt(vtotsq)*(x-0.5)
            print '1st %f' % (vx[i]) # prints the value here
    print (vx)
    velx = vx
    for i in xrange(0,natoms,1):
            y = random.random()
            vy[i]=4.0*math.sqrt(vtotsq)*(y-0.5)
            print '2nd %f' % (vy[i])
    print (vy)
    vely = vy
    for i in xrange(0,natoms,1):
            z = random.random()
            vz[i]=4.0*math.sqrt(vtotsq)*(z-0.5)
            print '3rd %f' % (vz[i])
    print (vz)
    velz = vz

    for i in xrange(0,natoms,1):
            print 'vx %d is %f' %(i,vx[i])

    print (vx)
    print '\n'
    print (vy)
    print '\n'
    print (vz)
    print '\n'
    print (velx)   # unfortunately veld, vely and velz all are still the same equal to vz
    print '\n'
    print (vely)
    print '\n'
    print (velz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your lists are simply references to the same `list` object, so changing one appears to change them all. To actually copy a list, you can `slice` the whole thing:

```
velx = vx[:]
```

or explicitly create a new list:

```
velx = list(vx)
```

But the neatest way to do what you want is a list comprehension, which creates and fills the list in one step:

```
vx = [4.0 * math.sqrt(vtotsq) * (random.random() - 0.5) for _ in range(natoms)]
```

Or, better:

```
vtotsqrt = math.sqrt(vtotsq) # sqrt is hard, do this once
vx = [4 * vtotsqrt * (random.random() - 0.5) for _ in range(natoms)]
```

Note that `range(0, x, 1)` is equivalent to `range(x)`. Assuming you want the three lists to contain different random values, you should run this three times rather than copying the lists.

Comment: Or you can use `vy = list(vx)` which provides better self-documentation and is clearer to beginners than slicing

Comment: I tried both the methods, they work fine. Thanks a lot. But I am still not very clear where I am referencing to the same 'list'. Could you please elaborate, I am relatively new to Python. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You don't actually show in your code where you originally create `vx`, `vy` and `vz`, you just start changing elements in them (`vx[i] = ...`). If you add the earlier code, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see what you are telling. Ok, so if I initially created all these arrays separately, initialized them with zero and then tried to change these values according to my code, will that work?

Comment: Yes, but you could create empty lists `[]` and `.append()` the values, rather than filling with zeroes to begin with.